# Angular 8 call a function in another function

Tags: angular, function

I have made a FormGroup in my Angular app like this:

```
  registrationForm: FormGroup;
  this.registrationForm = this.fb.group({
  orga: ['', [Validators.required, this.organismeValidator.bind(this)]],
  });
```

But my problem is that, when I enter in the function "dateFin", I want to recall the organismeValidator of my form. But it seems to never rechange the error of my"OrganismeValidator". For exemple, when "myDtFin" is not null, I would like to return a null error for this control, And in my case, it never changes"

```
    organismeValidator(control: AbstractControl) {
    // this.serviceHttp.getAllPensions().subscribe(resp => {
    // this.pensionsInvalidite = resp;
    if (this.pensionsInvalidite) {
      for (const pension of this.pensionsInvalidite) {
        if (!pension.dtFin) {
          if (control.value === pension.organisme.code && !this.myDtFin) {
            console.log('yes');
            return { organismeValidator: true };
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  datefin(myDtFin) {
    this.myDtFin = myDtFin;
    this.organismeValidator.call(this.myForm);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

please return null if it's valid other wise return validation error as an object. try that out like below

```
 if (this.pensionsInvalidite) {
      for (const pension of this.pensionsInvalidite) {
        if (!pension.dtFin) {
          if (control.value === pension.organisme.code && !this.myDtFin) {
            console.log('yes');
            return null;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return { organismeValidator: false };
```